# Identify 2011 set number, red car with criminal minifigure

Tags: set-identification, city

This bag is from a 2011 set, it's 150-250 pieces and it appears to be a car.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is from set [60007: High Speed Chase](http://brickset.com/sets/60007-1/High-Speed-Chase) based on [Chains M Plate M 5 Ø¸3, 2 Hole](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6061039). There are only two sets with this part in Medium Stone Grey. The other set is the Star Wars UCS B-wing

Comment: Since this answer was written, the [Technic Link Tread](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3873&idColor=86#T=C&C=86) has appeared in Light Bluish Gray in five additional sets.